# NodeJS, MongoDb, Express, & PassportJS Local Method req.user is undefined and deserialize & serialize functions not executing

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, passport.js

I have googled and tried so many solutions and I am really stuck on this for days. req.user is undefined, deserialize and serialize functions aren't getting called.

My connection to mongodb atlas is working fine, sessions are being created and stored in database and cookies are also being created with reference to sessionId. Login is authenticating to the correct route but req.user is undefined.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cors = require("cors");
var session = require('express-session');
var createError = require('http-errors');
var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
require('dotenv').config();
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const passport = require("passport");
const LocalStrategy = require("passport-local").Strategy;
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

mongoose.connect('my-secret-connection', { 
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  useNewUrlParser : true,
});
const db = mongoose.connection;
db.on("error", console.error.bind(console, "mongo connection error"));

const User = mongoose.model("User", new Schema(
  {
    username: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      maxlength: 256,
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    firstname: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      maxlength: 256,
    },
    lastname: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      maxlength: 256,
    },
    phone_number: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      maxlength: 20,
    },
    admin: {
      type: Boolean,
    },
  }), 'users'
);

const authenticateUser = (username, password, done) => {
  User.findOne({ username: username }, (err, user) => {
    if (err) {
      return done(err);
    }
    if (!user) {
      return done(null, false, { message: "Incorrect username/email" });
    }
    bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, (err, res) => {
      if (err) {
        return done(err);
      }
      if (res) {
        // Passwords match! Log user in.
        return done(null, user);
      } else {
        // Passwords do not match!
        return done(null, false, { message: "Incorrect password" });
      }
    });
  });
};

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.use(session({
  secret: 'some-session-secret', 
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  store: MongoStore.create({
    mongoUrl: uri,
    dbName: 'metadata',
  }),
  cookie: {
    maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
  },
}));

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(authenticateUser));

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  console.log('Serialize:', user.id); // never reaches this statement
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
  console.log("Deserialize:", id); // never reaches this statement
  User.findOne(id, (err, user) => {
    done(err, user);
 });
});

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser('some-session-secret'));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(cors());
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.locals.currentUser = req.user;
  console.log("User", req.user); // undefined
  next();
});

app.use('/', indexRouter);

app.post('/sign-up', function(req, res, next) {
  bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10, (err, hashedPassword) => {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }
    const user = new User({
      username: req.body.username.trim(),
      password: hashedPassword,
      firstname: req.body.firstname.trim(),
      lastname: req.body.lastname.trim(),
      phone_number: req.body.phone_number.trim(),
    }).save((err, doc) => {
      if (err) {
        return next(err);
      }
      res.redirect('http://localhost:3000/log-in');
    });
  });
});

app.post('/log-in', function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info, status) {
    if (err) {
      return next(err)
    }
    if (!user) {
      return res.redirect('http://localhost:3000/log-in')
    }
    if (user.admin === true) {
      return res.redirect('http://localhost:3000/admin');
    }
    res.redirect('http://localhost:3000/')
  })(req, res, next);
})
```

Comment: On which api call? post /login ?

Comment: @xlmouto I am creating a form on the client/React and POSTing to /sign-up route on form submit. Then authenticating login with POST form on client side and using passport local method on back-end. req.user is undefined in both /sign-up and /log-in routes. Deserialize and serialize never get called.

Answer (score 0):

Usually we keep user information in `req.user` once after validating the user's unique authentication token.

`req.user` doesn't exist in real and developers create a middle-ware for authenticated routes so that all the incoming routes will be authenticated with that token and stores the data of user explicitly as `req.user`

I didn't find writing req.user anywhere in your code rather found reading it in the common middleware so you caught up with errors.

Hope this helps!